# Laptop AP not showing up on Galaxy Tab

Tags: windows-xp, connection, wireless-access-point

I have setup my Windows XP laptop to be a WiFi AP. Next, I connected to the AP using proper authentication. My expectation is that, after connecting, it will show up on other devices. In the past, I  have done similar setup and I was able to access it from my other PC.

Now I am trying this is a Galaxy Tab 2, but the AP is not being listed on the available network. I was able to connect to other WiFi AP from elsewhere using the same Galaxy Tab, and nearby devices are also being listed.

Why is it the AP setup on my windows XP laptop isn't showing up on the list of WiFi devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not eventually make it work. Not sure if it's due to different generation of WiFi device. I had to get an independent WiFi device :)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and seems it is a weakness of Android system.

Finally I solved that by installing connectify to share connection. Its light version is free and enough.

Comment: is that with windows XP?

Comment: I think so although I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I tried this and no luck. Just to add, the signal strength is shown as zero. Although I am not sure as to why it should be zero.

Comment: In my cell phone, the signal is zero before I input correct password, while the password accepted everything works fine. Sorry I don't know what is the problem in your side.

Comment: I am also confused about the problem at my side. I was able to setup the thing properly in the past. Just to add, signal strength is full before connecting from my end, but zero just after I connect.